# VBA transform rows to column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet in excel which looks like this

```
name          variant1          value1          variant2          value2
-----         --------          ------          --------          ------    
name1         variantA1         valueA1         variantB1         valueB1
name2         variantC2         valueC2         variantD2         valueD2
```

And I want to transform it to such a structure:

```
name          variant          value
----          --------         ------
name1         
              variantA1        valueA1
              variantB1        valueB2
name2         
              variantC2        valueC2
              variantD2        valueD2
```

I will use this macro quite often, it may happen that there will be 10 different variants for each name and I don't know how many rows will be in the worksheet.

I've written VBA macro and I'm not sure why it doesn't work:

```
Sub import_format()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim NumberOfVariants As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ColumnIndex As Long


Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NumberOfVariants = 2
ColumnIndex = 2 '<~~ index of the first variant


For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ Set 2 if row 1 has headers
    i = i + 1
    ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + NumberOfVariants).Insert shift:=xlDown
    i = i - 1
    For j = 0 To (NumberOfVariants * 2) - 1
        ws.Range(Cells(ColumnIndex + (j * 2), i), Cells(ColumnIndex + (j * 2) + 1, i)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        ws.Range(Cells(ColumnIndex + (j * 2), i + j + 1), Cells(ColumnIndex + (j * 2) + 1, i + j + 1)).Paste
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

The way I tried to to this was to insert rows = number of variants and cut and paste proper values.

I will be grateful for all the hints! ;-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it doesn't work? What's the current results?

Comment: Where is `valueB1` in the transformed worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :)

```
Option Explicit
Sub import_format()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j, LastRow, ColumnIndex, NumberOfVariants As Integer


Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NumberOfVariants = 4
ColumnIndex = 2 '<~~ index of the first variant


For i = 2 To LastRow + (LastRow - 2) * (NumberOfVariants - 1) Step NumberOfVariants '<~~ Set 2 if row 1 has headers; Actual last row = current last row + lines which will be inserted
    ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + NumberOfVariants - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown 'Insert rows based on number of variants
    For j = 2 To (NumberOfVariants - 1) * 2 Step 2 'Walking through the variants, starting in column 2, variant + value are 2 columns, therefore using step 2
        ws.Range(Cells(i, ColumnIndex + j), Cells(i, ColumnIndex + j + 1)).Cut _
        Destination:=ws.Range(Cells(i + j / 2, ColumnIndex), Cells(i + j / 2, ColumnIndex + 1))
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to use `Cut` and `Paste`. Use direct assignment with `Range("A1").Resize(10,3).Value = Range("K1").Resize(10,3).Value` for example.